# automatically replace characters in stringstream

Tags: c++, string, replace, stream

I was searching for a way to replace characters in a `ostringstream` after I've filled it with string content but there are only some very inefficient solutions which extract the `string`, modify it and put it back into the `ostringstream`.

Now I wonder if there's a way to automatically replace those characters at the time I add the string. E.g.

```
ostringstream my_json;
my_json << replace_singlequotes;  # modify the stringsteam once
my_json << "{'this':";
my_json << " 'is valid JSON'}";
std::cout << my_json.str();

output:
{"this": "is valid JSON"}
```

Can you write a custom filter for a `ostringstream` similar to the format modifiers like `std::hex`, etc. which modifies a given string before piping it into the stream?

Or is there any other way to replace characters in a `ostringstream` except running `std::replace()` on `my_json.str()` as suggested in other questions and howtos?

Comment: I think the second code snippet will be more helpful for you than the first one.

Comment: Note: If it is just to write json in an easier way that escaping quote, you may use raw string: `R"({"this": "is valid JSON"})"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an user defined manipulator for this purpose. Please see the example as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class replace_singlequotes {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const replace_singlequotes &);
private:
    std::string str;
public:
    replace_singlequotes(std::string);
};

replace_singlequotes::replace_singlequotes(std::string str) {
    this->str = str;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const replace_singlequotes &value) {
    std::string result = value.str;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
        if (result.at(i) == '\'') {
            result.at(i) = '\"';
        }
    }
    os << result;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::ostringstream my_json;
    my_json << replace_singlequotes("{'this': 'is valid JSON'}");
    std::cout << my_json.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be as follows:

```
{"this": "is valid JSON"}
```

**Update:** Here is one another way of doing this using the concept of operator overloading:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class String {
private:
    std::string value;
public:
    String operator=(const std::string value);
    friend std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream &out, String const &str);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, String &str);
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out, const String &str) {
    std::string result = str.value;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
        if (result.at(i) == '\'') {
            result.at(i) = '\"';
        }
    }
    out << result;
    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, String &str) {
    in >> str.value;
    return in;
}

String String::operator=(const std::string value) {
    this->value = value;
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    std::stringstream out;
    String str;

    str = "{'this': 'is valid JSON'}";
    out << str;

    std::cout<<out.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Note:

- The above program will also produce the same output as `{"this": "is
  valid JSON"}`
- Here, the advantage is that you can use the `insertion operator (<<)`
  directly to replace the single quote by a double quote.
- The above code snippet uses the concept of operator overloading while
  the initial example was using user defined manipulators.

If you would like to use `replace_singlequotes` as a manipulator and
   if you would like to combine the overloading concept with this, I would suggest
   that you follow the steps below:

1. Declare a `boolean` flag called as `replace_singlequotes` in    the
   class.
2. Make it `static`.
3. Check if the flag value is `true/false` and decide on if you have
   to replace the single quote by a double quote in the overloaded body of the insertion operator(`<<`).

Comment: can't you just provide a function `string replace_singlequotes(string s) {replace(s.begin(), s.end(), '\'', '"'); return s;}` to achieve the same result as in your first example? The problem is that you have to write `replace_singlequote(<intput>)` every time rather than modifying the state of the `stringstream`.

Comment: Yes. You can. But that won't showcase an example for manipulator. But if you look at the second example, you will never have to write `replace_singlequote(<intput>)` because the definition of insertion operator itself will take care of that.